# Multiple projects with trunk/branches/tags each

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, git-branch

I am starting a new project and I only have an SVN server available. After doing a bit of research on SVN, I figured out that the best repository structure for my project would be the following:

```
/ProjectMain
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags

/ProjectAnnex    # will not be branched
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags

/Documentation
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags

/Research        # will not be branched
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags
```

as I will have multiple unrelated projects and documents. However I dislike using SVN and would feel much more comfortable using Git through Git-SVN.

How could I import this existing repo with `git-svn clone` or by editing my `.git/config` file? I saw that it is possible to use wildcards in the fetch/branches/tags config parameters, but how to use them in the beginning of a path?!

How will the branching process happen as I branch out from `trunk`? How will the branches correctly be stored in the various `branches` folders?

If you believe that this structure is too cumbersome, what would you rather suggest?

Thank you in advance for your precious help,
Franck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a different git repository for each project. Otherwise, all your branches and tags would be mixed together, which is probably not what you need. So, use

```
git svn clone --stdlayout http://example.com/path/to/ProjectMain
```

for your first project,

```
git svn clone --stdlayout http://example.com/path/to/ProjectAnnex
```

for the second one, and so on.

Comment: Good point! Shouldn't I rather use ``git svn clone --stdlayout http...``, as every project has its own trunk/branch/tags folders? Finally, would I have issues w.r.t. ``git-svn`` linear history? Thanks!!

Comment: @FranckStudiesCommEng Yes you should. I added that to the answer. This way, git-svn should properly extract the history of individual branches.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Also, is there a way to ``update`` and ``commit`` all changes in every repositories at once?

Comment: @FranckStudiesCommEng You may write a script for that, but every git commit would still result in a separate svn commit.

Comment: I believe it will make the history even cleaner! Thank you, Evgeny, for your fast answer!